# Alternative to Eval() to avoid vulnerability detection when scanning with the Fortify tool

Tags: javascript, fortify

The Fortify tool is marking me as vulnerable in the use of Eval().
The code looks like this:

```
function whatever(id1, name, id2, id3) {
    try {
        var func = "";
        var populateScript = "";
        name = "pp_" + name;
        if (loadFunction && loadFunction.length > 0) {
            func = loadFunction.replace(/\"/gi, "'")
        }
        populateScript = ejecutarPopulate.format(id1, name, id2, id3, func);
        eval(populateScript);
    } catch (e) {
        Message(e);
    }
}
```

ejecutarPopulate get from DB some values to populate a dropdown menu and construct the HTML.

Is it dangerous to use Eval()?
What could be the alternative?

Comment: It's dangerous to use eval if there's any way that user supplied data can make it into the string being evalled, without bullet-proof escaping of the value. Database data that was originally supplied by a user does count. If this is just updating some HTML, why does this need to use eval?

Comment: could you supply smt that populateScript  could be ?